# Limit to cron job with PHP

Tags: php, cron, web-hosting

I have a Cron Job with PHP which I want to set up on my webhost, but at the moment the script takes about 20 seconds to run with only 3 users data being refreshed. If I get a 1000 users - gonna take ages. Is there an alternative to Cron Job? Will my web host let me run a cron job which takes, for example, 10 minutes to run?

Comment: what kind of hosting do you have shared hosting? Then no way are you allowed to run a PHP script for 10 minutes straight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron job can be as long as you want.

The main problem for you is that you must ensure **the next cron job execution is not occuring while the first one is still running**. You have a lot of solutions to avoid it, basically use a semaphore.

It can be a lock file, a record in database. Your cron job should check if the previous one is finished or not. A good thing is maybe sending you an email if he cannot run because of a long previous job (this way you'll have some notice alerting you that something is maybe getting wrong) By default cron jobs with bad error dstatus on exit are outputing all the standard output to the email of the account running the job, depending on how is configured the platform you could use this behavior or build an smtp connexion on the job (or store the alert in a database table).

If you want some alternatives to cron jobs you should have a look at **work queues**. You can mix work queues with a cron job, or use work queue in apache-php envirronment, lot of solutions, but the main idea is to make on single queue of things that should be done, and execute them one after the other (but be careful, if you handle theses tasks very slowly you'll get a big fat waiting queue).

Comment: ok good advice, thanks, i only want to run it once a day, so i hope that it wont take longer than 24 hours to run! I was coming more from a PHP timeout or similar, is that going to happen with a hefty script?

Comment: you need to check the value of max_execution_time php configuration setting when running in cli mode (it can/should be different than the one in apache mode), check as well memory_limit.

Answer (score 1):

A cron job shouldn't have any bearing on how long it's 'job' takes to complete. If you're jobs are taking 20 seconds to complete, it's PHP's fault, not cronjob.

> Will my web host let me run a cron job which takes, for example, 10 minutes to run?

Ask your webhost.

If you want to learn about optimizing php scripts, take a look at [Profiling PHP Code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+profiling).

Comment: ok i understand, but what if my script takes 10 minutes to run - what implications does this have?

Comment: @benhowdle89 It's hard to answer that question without more information. Normally, an OS doesn't care about how long something takes to run. But there are always other factors. Is it pegging any of the system resources (CPU, RAM, DISK I/O)? Will other services suffer because of the system-utilization (i.e. will apache hang because the cron is taking up all the cpu)? Does your host implement any kind of limits?